# Autofac - Registering instance type that takes interface as parameter

Tags: api, dependency-injection, autofac, ioc-container

I am very new to Autofac and not able to understand the syntax for registration. I have following calsses/interfaces :

```
//Interface
public interface ISender
{
    void Send();
}


//implementations 
public class Post : ISender
{
    public void Send()
    {
        //Post implementation
    }
}

public class Email : ISender
{
    public void Send()
    {
        //Email implementation
    }
}
```

And a class that calls these implementations

```
public class Consumer
{
    ISender Sender;

    public Consumer(ISender sender)
    {
        Sender = sender
    }

    public void Act()
    {
        Sender.Send();
    }   
}
```

Now, which implementation to call is to be decided in a controller, so I tried using IIndex from [this page](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#resolving-with-an-index) like:

```
public calss PostController
{
    Consumer ConsumerObject;
    public PostController(IIndex<string, Consumer> consumer)
    {
        ConsumerObject = consumer["post"];
    }

}

public class EmailController
{
    Consumer ConsumerObject;
    public PostController(IIndex<string, Consumer> consumer)
    {
        ConsumerObject = consumer["email"];
    }
}
```

Firstly, is it correct or doable? Now the problem is I don't understand how to register in Autofac. So, How can we register Consumer and ISender in Autofac ?? Please suggest if there is any better/alternative way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of registering components in Autofac is described widely in the documentation [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html). And how to use keyed services is described in the documentation you linked.

Basically you have to create `ContainerBuilder`, register all your components and build the container itself, based on the project type you have.

In your situation you need to use the following registrations:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Post>().Keyed<ISender>("post");
builder.RegisterType<Email>().Keyed<ISender>("email");
builder.RegisterType<Consumer>();
```

If you use ASP.NET WebApi (I assume that based on the fact you are using Controllers), you need to register your controllers

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

or for MVC

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
```

Now, there are various way to pick the `Consumer` with proper `ISender` implementation (I assume you want to pick proper implementation in controller).

One would be to inject `IIndex<string, ISender>` to `Consumer` class and pass the proper key string to it as well:

```
public class Consumer
{
    ISender Sender;

    public Consumer(string type, IIndex<string, ISender> sender)
    {
        Sender = sender[type];
    }

    public void Act()
    {
        Sender.Send();
    }   
}
```

Then, in controller you could use `Func` injection:

```
public class PostController
{
    Consumer ConsumerObject;
    public PostController(Func<string, Consumer> consumer)
    {
        ConsumerObject = consumer("post");
    }
}

public class EmailController
{
    Consumer ConsumerObject;
    public EmailController(Func<string, Consumer> consumer)
    {
        ConsumerObject = consumer("email");
    }
}
```

Another could be registering Consumer twice with `Register` method and resolving `ISender` in registration time.